# Tcl: Interaction of extension loading and threads

Tags: package, loading, tcl

Can several instances of a Tcl_PackageInitProc() be executing
concurrently (in different threads), if TCL was configured
for threads?

For reasons of backward compatibility, I believe
invocations of the initialization and unload procedures must be
serialized.

The manual is silent on the behavior: are invocations of these routines
serialized, or must extension writers deal with synchronization, in
particular mutual exclusion, in these routines?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl does *not* guarantee that those functions are called in a serialized way; if your code cares, it must use a suitable mutex. Tcl provides portable primitives in its C library, which you use like this:

```c
#include <tcl.h>

// MUCH easier to have this as its own function
static void OneTimeSetup(void) {
    static int doneSetup;
    TCL_DECLARE_MUTEX(myMutex);

    Tcl_MutexLock(&myMutex);
    if (!doneSetup) {
        // Do critical once-only setup here
        doneSetup = 1;
    }
    Tcl_MutexUnlock(&myMutex);
}

int My_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    // Declare the API version we're using, e.g., for 8.5...
    if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, "8.5", 0) == NULL)
        return TCL_ERROR;

    // Call out to our setup code
    OneTimeSetup();

    // Install Tcl commands/variables/... here

    // Ready for action!
    return TCL_OK;
}
```